Jade Plant (Crassula Ovata) health concerns
I've been checking on my jade plant, which is standing in full sun. I moved it outdoors arround 2 months ago, when temperatures went above 12°C day & night. I was on holiday for a week, before my holidays the plant looked fine! However now some brownish / scaly spots appeared on the underside on some of the leaves and some yellow spots appeared at the top of the plant. New growth is not affected. Also one thing I've noticed is that the plant just randomly tipped over a few days ago from one side to the other (however without it loosening in the soil). Therefore I checked the roots a few days ago (found nothing suspicious, no signs of fungicide & or root rot), then staked it up with 3mm eloxated alinium wire.
Here are a few images of the plant.



Final question:
Is there anything to concern about for the plant? What should I change? What do I have to improve to put the plant in better health again.
Thanks in advance for any help!
